# Yii urlManager get 404 error in share hosting?

Tags: php, yii

I have somefile in :

```
//phpfile
public_html/protected/modules/news/NewsModule.php
public_html/protected/modules/news/controller/HomeController.php
public_html/protected/modules/news/views/home/index.php
```

My htacess:

```
RewriteEngine on
## if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#
## otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

main.php

```
'modules'=>array(
    'news' => array(
        'class'=>'application.modules.news.NewsModule',
    ),
    'backend'=>array(
        'class'=>'application.modules.backend.BackendModule',
    ),
    'console' => array(
        'class'=>'application.modules.console.ConsoleModule',
    ),  
),
 //rewrite
'components'=>array(
 'urlManager'=>array(
        'rules'=>array(
            '' => 'site/index',
            // For home page
            'gii'=>'gii',
            'gii/<controller:\w+>'=>'gii/<controller>',
           'gii/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'gii/<controller>/<action>',
             // news folder , home controller , index action
             '<type:en>' => '/news/home/index',
             '<type:vi>' => '/news/home/index',

            '<type:en>/<slug:project>' => '/news/project/posts2',
            '<type:vi>/<slug:du-an>' => '/news/project/posts2',
            '<type:en>/<slug:project>/<title:.*?>' => '/news/project/postdetail',
            '<type:vi>/<slug:du-an>/<title:.*?>' => '/news/project/postdetail',

        )
    ),
),
```

I don't know why when i run example.com/en or example.com/en/project vv... it return 500 error . but in my localhost it work normarlly

Comment: 500's errors are internal server errors. See or paste the app.log if you want help.